# How to perform two tasks on a single button click or event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have a button on clicking it, it increments the count value by calling the function incrementIndex. But i would also like to add a String to the array list for the same event.
A simple code snippet is provided below.

**Java Script**

```
var count=0;
function incrementIndex() {
count += 1;
}
```

**ArrayList**

```
<%
ArrayList arr= new ArrayList();
String ele="3,2";
%>
```

**Button:**

```
<button onclick="incrementIndex()">Button 1</button>
```

Comment: Are you mixing Scriplet with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, basically this is a JSP code. Where we can use both Scriptlets and Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a single button click invoke two more tasks (or whatever) simply nest the other tasks into the function bound to `onclick`

So instead of:

```
<button onclick="incrementIndex()">Button 1</button>
```

you will have

```
<button onclick="increment_and_add_string()">Button 1</button>
```

then you need to have this code

```
function increment_and_add_string(){
     incrementIndex();  //this will call the increment function
     arr.add(ele);  //this will call the method add to arr passing it ele.
}
```

Obviously, you will have some scoping issues, and without more intimate knowledge of where you get `arr` and `ele` from, I can't help you there.  But the gist is you have called a function that does several tasks, and have bound it to the button click event.

Answer (score 0):

call the sring function at the end of the increment function.

```
$(function(){
   $(#button").click(function(){
  incrementIndex();  //this will call the increment function
 arr.add(ele);  //this will call the method add to arr passing it ele.
});
 });
```

or something like

```
$(function(){
   $(#button").click(function(){
   $("#").increment();//what ever your incrementing function is
   $.get("ServerResponce.asp"), function( data ) { // call controller or server action
   $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
});
});
```

Comment: the `stringFunction` appears to be server-side code

Comment: Can you not use ajax to render/return server side code?

Comment: To add the string to the ArrayList, the code is arr.add(ele);but the problem is how do i write it in such a way that the function is invoked only when i click the button..

Comment: @user2900314 you nest the code inside of the $(#button").click(function() call

Comment: @JTG you mean to say that I need to remove my increment function and replace it with $(function(){ $(#button").click(function(){$("#").increment();$.get("ServerResponce.asp"), function( data ) {
arr.add(ele);
   $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
});
});

Comment: @JTG,@Mark I am sorry I am new to these things.

Comment: Nest both functions within $("#button").click(function(){<!-- insert functions to be triggered" -->});

Comment: See my edit to the first example in the answer above, something like that should work, just give your button the id #button

Answer (score 0):

You can have a handler function that runs all other functions.

```
<button onclick="handleButton1Click()">Button 1</button>

<script>
var count = 0,
    stringList = [];

function incrementIndex() {

  count += 1;
}

function addString(string) {

  stringList.push(string)
}

function handleButton1Click(e) {

  addString(e.someEventProperty);
  incrementIndex();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to first understand how jsp is presented to the user in browser. Whatever is shown to the user in the browser is just html and javascript, having said this whatever java code you  have written in jsp is compiled and processed in JVM itself thus no java variable will be available to the end user in browser for further updation, on the contrary javascript runs in browser so you can do whatever you want with the help of javasscript in browser. 

Now coming to your problem, you have a List in java so its reference won't be available to you in browser so what you can do is you can have a javascript list and assign the java List to it. Now you will have an access to javascript list in the browser, do whatever you want to do with it as add/substract/concat etc and while submitting form, submit the value of that javascript list too in some hidden field and finally in your servlet/controller class you will have latest list using which prepare final updated java List.

Let say you java list is as below:

 <%
    List<Object> javaObjList = new ArrayList<Object>();
 %>

In your jsp assign it to java script variable as below
<script>
 var jsObjList = <%= javaObjList.toArrays()%>
</script>

Have some hidden field in you form as below:

<input type="hidden" name="finalList" id="finalListId"/>

Before form submission call a function which will do as follow:
<script>
function preSubmissionProcessing() {
   document.getElementById("finalListId").val = jsObjList; 
   // make sure jsObjList  is in scope so that accessible to this method
}
</script>

That's it
```